# Create nested objects without creating class in Java

Tags: java, class, dictionary, object

I want to create the following object for the response but I don't want to create the class for this. Is there any way I can achieve this using map or other util classes?

```
"conferenceData": {
    "createRequest": {
      "conferenceSolutionKey": {
        "type": "hangoutsMeet"
      },
      "requestId": "RANDOM_STRING2"
    }
  }
```

Comment: What JSON library are you using? You can probably use nested maps.

Comment: Do you really think making your own type will be harder than dealing with a `Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>>>`?

Comment: You want to create an object without a class?  So the simplest is to just interact with the JSONObject directly.  Downside is the code to do that is not going to give you any compile time safety, and accommodating things like field name changes is clunky.

Comment: @azurefrog using this, I will end up with an array of maps and I don't want that.
`"createRequest": {
      ["conferenceSolutionKey": {
        "type": "hangoutsMeet"
      },
      "requestId": "RANDOM_STRING2"]
    }`

Comment: You shouldn't use Maps or Lists, you should create a custom type that correctly encapsulates your data structure.  It will be easier to use in your code, and *much* easier to maintain if the data ever changes.

Comment: There is a method to map the json object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think below is the solution you are looking for...

```
Map<String, Object> conferenceData = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Object> createRequest = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Object> keyAndRequestId= new HashMap<>();
Map<String, String> type = new HashMap<>();

type.put("type", "hangoutsMeet");
keyAndRequestId.put("conferenceSolutionKey", type);
keyAndRequestId.put("requestId", "RANDOM_STRING2");
createRequest.put("createRequest", keyAndRequestId);
conferenceData.put("conferenceData", createRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use :

```
Map<String,Object> result = new ObjectMapper().readValue(JSON_SOURCE, HashMap.class);
```

Or if you are using org.json, JSONObject has a method toMap(). You can easily do :

```
Map<String, Object> myMap = myJsonObject.toMap();
```